# Apache Intermittant Hang is it Network Lag?

Tags: apache, networking, debian, lag

I have an intermittent lag on the web applications I am serving from Apache on a Debian box. Apache and MySQL check out. I am far from fully utilizing the box CPU/Memory. Still there is an intermittent lag. My theory is there is a network rate limit needing to be tweaked. Stats below.

## Apache Server Status

```
Current Time: Tuesday, 02-Jun-2020 14:36:53 EDT
Restart Time: Monday, 01-Jun-2020 01:00:03 EDT
Parent Server Config. Generation: 1
Parent Server MPM Generation: 0
Server uptime: 1 day 13 hours 36 minutes 50 seconds
Server load: 2.95 3.23 3.09
Total accesses: 1213060 - Total Traffic: 22.0 GB - Total Duration: 32311929295
CPU Usage: u396.94 s164.31 cu2065.15 cs789.27 - 2.52% CPU load
8.96 requests/sec - 170.5 kB/second - 19.0 kB/request - 26636.7 ms/request
296 requests currently being processed, 66 idle workers

WR.WWWW.KWW_W._W_KWWWWWWKWWWWW_WWWWK_WK_WWW_WW_RWWWWWKCWWWWWW._W
_WW_R_W_.__K_WWWW__WWWWWWKKWWWWWWKWWWW_W____WWWWWWWW_WWW_KWWWWWW
WWWWWWWW_.WWWWWK_WWW_WWKWWWWWWKWWKWK_WWWWWRKWWW.WW_KKWKWWWKW_WWW
WW.W_.K._WWWK_WW_K_K._WW..WWWWWWW_.W_WWWW_W_W.W_WWWW_.WWKWK_WKWW
_W_WWWW_W.WWWWWW.WWWW_K__..W.WW_WWWWWWWWKRW_WWW_C.W_KW_WWW_KW.._
..WWWWWWWCWWW.WWW_WKKWWWW_._WWW.....WWW.W_W.W._.KW...W...WWW.WWW
W..W..K..WW_.W._................W..._W.W.....K.W.K_...R..K...W.W
...W..W.............................................
```

## top

```
top - 14:31:14 up 79 days, 21:39,  3 users,  load average: 2.26, 2.57, 2.86
Tasks: 717 total,   1 running, 716 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  3.3 us,  0.7 sy,  0.2 ni, 95.7 id,  0.0 wa,  0.0 hi,  0.1 si,  0.0 st
MiB Mem :  64365.1 total,    539.8 free,   8847.0 used,  54978.4 buff/cache
MiB Swap:  65477.0 total,  63810.0 free,   1667.0 used.  54580.5 avail Mem
```

## ss -s

```
Total: 1934
TCP:   2362 (estab 1233, closed 1105, orphaned 2, timewait 1104)

Transport Total     IP        IPv6
RAW       0         0         0        
UDP       0         0         0        
TCP       1257      430       827      
INET      1257      430       827      
FRAG      0         0         0
```

## ulimit -n

`1024`

## ss -ntu | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n

```
    1 Local
    6 192.XXX.XXX.XXX
  100 127.0.0.1
  340 10.0.0.XX
  866 [
```

## ss -ntu | awk '{print $6}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -n

```
 ..........
lists # of ip connections. Besides 127.0.0.1 and [ there are 2 ips over 50.
   74 104.xxx.xxx.xxx
   91 12.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

## MySQL

`No processes running more than a second. Number of processes well within limits.`

I do not know what stats would be relevant beyond these in diagnosing network rate limiting issues. Any pointers would be appreciated.

## EDITED

CPU

- lscpu https://pastebin.com/Jha6F7J8

Apache Config

- apachectl -t -D DUMP_RUN_CFG https://pastebin.com/i1L2hnjH

Mysql

- SHOW GLOBAL STATUS https://pastebin.com/aQX4D01k
- SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES https://pastebin.com/L8EfmHfn
- SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST https://pastebin.com/GtqK2tET
- mysqltuner https://pastebin.com/GLhhKA9q

Optional Very Helpful Information

- top -bn1 https://pastebin.com/r94vpXe6
- iostat -xm 5 3 https://pastebin.com/R8YLK3QU
- ulimit -a https://pastebin.com/KUC3wqxU

Comment: Additional information request. 
# cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
A) Apache configuration
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top - 1st page  for most active apps, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions. PS use ulimit -a

Comment: Please use ulimit -a to determine limits and post it as well.  Ulimit -n is normally used to 'set' a limit for Open Files.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Question edited with the collected info.

Comment: Thank you for posting the data.  Analysis will begin today.  Will try to have suggestions posted within 24 hours.  Looking forward to providing useful suggestions.
Please view profile, Network profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.

Comment: Dorothy, Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Dorothy, Your system is very busy with activity. Not knowing the frequency and duration of the intermittent hangs puts us at a disadvantage.  One possible cause is com_drop_table had 3,318 uses in your 83 days of uptime. Another possible cause is volume of data read and written.  It appears innodb_data_written was 484TB in 83 days and yet MySQLTuner reports only 800K of data in 10 tables. Our General Log Analysis could likely identify the cause of this high activity. These suggestions will be a starting effort, more analysis and changes should be accomplished.

From your OS command prompt, 
ulimit -n 96000 would enable many more Open Files (handles) above today's 1024 limit.
This is a dynamic operation in Linux and does not require OS restart to be implemented.
For this change to persist across OS stop/start the following URL could be used as a guide.
Please use 96000, not 500000 - as in their example documentation.
    https://glassonionblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/increase-ulimit-and-file-descriptors-limit/

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
innodb_io_capacity=1900  # from 200 if you have SSD, 900 if you have magnetic storage to improve IOPS
net_buffer_length=32K  # from 16K to reduce malloc operations
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 1024 to conserve 90% of CPU cycles used for function
key_cache_segments=16  # from 0 to reduce mutex contention with MyISAM opens
key_cache_division_limit=50  # from 100 for Hot/Warm storage to reduce key_page_reads RPS of 18
aria_pagecache_division_limit=50  # from 100 for Hot/Warm storage to reduce aria_pagecache_reads RPS of 5K
read_rnd_buffer_size=64K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 27,707
```

These changes should reduce elapsed time to complete most queries.
Additional areas to consider include the use of Slow Query Log analysis to find where an index could avoid a table scan.  MySQLTuner reported more than 4 million joins performed without indexes.  Our FAQ page includes information on how you could find the tables needing indexes to avoid scans.  Let us know how these suggestions work for you.
Skype Talk works very well if you have the flexibility to use that form of communication.

Comment: Made the changes as suggested. MySQL crashed immediately. Got signal 11, backtrace rported buffer overflow detected then Fatal signal 6 while backtracing

Comment: @Dorothy Do you have SSD or magnetic storage?  What did you use for innodb_io_capacity? Could you post last 400 lines of error log where it tried to start?

Comment: I do not have SSD. Oh, so was I supposed to set innodb_io_capacity to 900? Than the crash was due to overuse of io?

Comment: Yes, please.  Most likely caused the overrun.

Comment: Skype works great.  My Skype ID is wlhauck@aol.com  in Birmingham, AL, please make contact.